# USPTO classification number

Tags: uspto, bulk-download

I'm trying to get classification numbers for all a large number of patents through USPTO bulk download.  The bulk download files come in three different formats--appended with ipg, pg, and pftaps respectively.  I'm wondering how can I find the same patent classification number for all three formats.  I don't really care if it is a US classification number or an international classification number, but when I find one type of classification number, I can't find the same type in a different format.  The type of identifier in all three formats would be helpful as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure this is on topic. Have you looked for cpc or ipc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The US and EPO have gone to a unified patent classification system, the Cooperative Patent Classification (CPC).  The USPTO recently reclassified all of the US patents to assign them a CPC classification.    You can download a master file of all US patents with CPC classification at https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/data2/patent/classification/cpc/

I believe that is what you were requesting.