# ICL_Class from patentpy package to CPC class

Tags: patent-applications, uspto, icl-class

I downloaded USPTO bulkdata using patentpy package (https://github.com/JYProjs/patentpy). There is an ICL_class (International classification) field here. I need help to map this to CPC_class and CPC_subclass.

The link https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/data2/patent/classification/cpc/ mentioned in [USPTO classification number](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17280/uspto-classification-number) isn't working.

Kindly advise how can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately you aren't going to get programming advice here. Perhaps in StackOverflow. In any case, a google search is a good starting point including https://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/html/conB82Ytoipc.html and https://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/pdf/us901tocpc.pdf and https://www.cooperativepatentclassification.org/cpcConcordances

Comment: The link that isn't working might be here: https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/data/patent/classification/cpc/

Comment: @EricS - Thank you for the link. Will check. I am not seeking programming advice. I am requesting help on mapping ICL_Class to CPC fields. If there is any document that relates these two fields. Thanks again for the prompt replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will not be a foolproof 1:1 correspondence. The CPC was developed by a joint effort of USPTO and EPO to create a common system essentially merging USPC and European classification systems. The European system was originally based on the international system.

If you google concordance between IPC and CPC you will find [Statistical mapping: IPC to CPC](https://www.epo.org/searching-for-patents/helpful-resources/first-time-here/classification/cpc/ipccpc.html).

It has disclaimers as to its usefulness but does include an XML version of the *not 1:1 mapping*.

Comment: The biggest problem here is that CPC is like a more detailed version of the IPC with additional subgroups. CPC has most, if not all, the classifications of the IPC, and additional ones. So if you want to have a CPC-equivalent of an IPC, it will probably be the same code. But if you want to have an IPC-equivant of a CPC, it could be that there is none because the IPC lacks the additional subgroup.

Comment: If you follow the link, it is more complicated. "We display the three most pertinent CPC symbols, in decreasing order of relevance. Note that the confidence level of the mapping is low when the number of families statistically processed is small and/or when the statistical dispersion of the mapping of one IPC symbol to many CPC symbols is significant. "

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Thanks a lot for the explanations.

Comment: @theEuropeist - Sure, thank you!